# UDP server listening in LAN for datagram packets using Datagramsockets in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, udp

I've searched too much but didn't get the answer, I am actually sending the data packet from client app to server app in LAN, there will be more than one client sending the packets to the server, Server on the other side will just receive those packet from the client apps and store the packets in database and the server won't send any reply to client, Does my server is required to be threaded using thread class ?
Please also tell me when does we need threaded client or server?

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private DatagramSocket socket;
String str;
EditText et;
Button bt;
private static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;
private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.255";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

    bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


             et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
             str = et.getText().toString();
                new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
        }
    });



}


class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {


        try {
            socket = new DatagramSocket(SERVERPORT);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            InetAddress serverAddr = null;
            try {
                serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
      DatagramPacket packet = newDatagramPacket(str.getBytes(),str.length(),serverAddr,SERVERPORT);
                try {
                    socket.send(packet);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        } 

    }

}
```

Comment: Is your "server" also running in Android? If it won't send any reply, how can the Clients know their messages have been received? Or is this irrelevant?

Comment: server running is also android app, and I don't want to put this thing in server to let know the clients about their sent message @Fildor

Comment: You know that with UDP packets can get lost without notice to the sender? So I guess, you are aware of that and the application does not need every packet to arrive at the server. Other question: how will the clients know the server's IP? About Threading: Are you planning to use a "Service"? Then you'll probably need a "Handler"...

Comment: servers IP is pre defined, and please tell me about something handler and service, I know nothing about it. @Fildor

Comment: See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). I'm assuming, the server shall be listening during some longer period of time and not just a few minutes, right?

Comment: yes server will also be on and always be listening for the messages. @Fildor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDP servers don't need to be multi-threaded. You only need one socket, and there are no connections, so there is no necessity to use threads.

Comment: and what about the client side, It needed to be multi-threaded or not? the purpose of client is to just send the message to server on LAN.

Comment: If using blocking I/O, I'd give it its own Thread (but just that one), though. You'd agree with that, @EJP?

Comment: @AmeerHumza In the Client, you can use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for sending to avoid blocking the GUI.

Comment: @Fildor check my question I have edited it with my client class, Tell me whether it will get my job done ?

Comment: @EJP check my client side in my question that whether it will get my job done?

Comment: @AmeerHumza Why would the client side need to be multi-threaded? From the UDP point of view the only reason would be that you want to send and receive at the same time. Do you?

Comment: @Fildor There should be a thread dedicated to the UDP socket, yes.

Comment: @EJP as far as client is concerned i have tested in client while creating the socket in the main thread android was giving the fatal exception for it so again i threaded the client too and in server side tell me when more than one client will be sending the data at the same time then the server without the thread won't be able to receive both client messages?